# "He is what is known as a bellyacher"

Tags: relative-pronouns

I think "*He is **who** is known as a bellyacher*" is right because "who" there functions as the subject of the clause and "he" is a human being rather than a thing. My teacher said it is a practice and just memorize it but I wondered if there is a explanation.

Comment: It's "syntactically valid", but would rarely if ever be uttered by a native Anglophone. For most contexts, ***who is*** is utterly redundant (we just say *He is known as a bellyacher*). But if we *wanted* to include a second [pro]noun in the reference, we'd more likely say *He is **someone** who is known as a bellyacher* (or *He is **a man** who...*, or similar). OR we use the idiomatically established format *X is what is known as Y*, where it's syntactically irrelevant whether X is a thing or a person.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - people often say things like _he is what you might call a bloody idiot_.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: [*Google NGrams*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=He+is+*+is+known&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) suggests ***what*** is the *only* word likely to appear between ***He is...*** and ***...is known***.

Comment: I think you mean **memorize**, not *mesmerize*!

Comment: It's probably the same reason we ask ***What are you called? / What do people call you?*** rather than ***Who are you called?...*** The "label" is a "thing", even if what it *refers* to is a person.

Comment: "He is [the type of person] that is known as a bellyacher."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use "what" instead of "who" because the pronoun refers to a concept (a type of person), not the person himself. Kate Bunting notes (in a comment above) that your sentence is equivalent to:

> He is [the type of person that] is known as a bellyacher.